# How do you redirect to Create route when Edit route has no results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using Backpack for Laravel (and am new to it).

I have a menu item called "My Profile".

When a user is created, I do not automatically create a profile entry in the DB until they save one.

The relationship is a 1-1 between a user and their profile.

When clicking "My Profile", I am linking to the edit route:

`<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('profile') }}/{{backpack_user()->id}}/edit"><i class="nav-icon la la-id-badge"></i> My Profile</a></li>`

If a user has already saved a profile, this works correctly. However, if they have not it returns an error: "No query results for model [App\Models\Profile] 2"

In those cases can I reroute to the Create route? Am I going about this the right way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how Laravel backpack handles this, as it is a wrapper for Laravel code, but typically if you navigate to `/{id}/edit` (or similar), `id` is pulled out of the URL and executed against `Profile::findOrFail($id)`, which will trigger that error if no result is found for the ID. If you can modify that code, you can use `::find()`, and if the result is `null`, redirect appropriately. If you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75584747/edit) to show what handles that URL (i.e. the Controller), then we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using:

```
@if(\App\Models\profile::find(backpack_user()->id))
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('profile') }}/{{backpack_user()->id}}/edit"><i class="nav-icon la la-id-badge"></i> My Profile</a></li>
@endif
```

In the `sidebar_content.blade` file.

Thanks for the help Tim.

Comment: Nice! That's a good solution too; simply don't show the URL if there's nothing to navigate to 

Comment: Just to add a note ZcomZ, if you do it that way you will be making a database query on every page load. 
I think you should eagerload your profile relation in the user model, and then use `if(backpack_user()->profile)`.
That way the profile will be loaded in the same query to get the database user. 
Cheers

Comment: Uuu good catch Pedro!